# How to omit key and value when creating list of dictionaries using comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I am creating a list of dictionaries from a separate list of dictionaries and transforming the content. I would like to conditionally exclude keys during the comprehension, but I'm not sure how. Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
old_dict_list = [
    { 'old_key_1': 'value1a', 'old_key_2': 'value2a', 'old_key_3': 'value3a'},
    { 'old_key_1': 'value1b', 'old_key_2': 'value2b', 'old_key_3': 'value3b'},
]

new_dict_list = [
    {
        'new_key1': old_dict['old_key_1'],
        'new_key2': old_dict['old_key_2'], # exclude this key entirely if some condition is met
        'new_key3': old_dict['old_key_3'],
    }
    for old_dict in old_dict_list
]

print(new_dict_list)
```

I don't know of any way to conditionally exclude a key entirely when using comprehension like this. The only idea I've had is to use a fixed key value like None when the condition is met, then make a separate pass through the list of dictionaries and remove those None keys.

Is there any way to do this in just the one comprehension pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't get hung up on the fact you are making your new list in a comprehension.

Clearly if you can transform a dictionary from the old format to the new format this is just

```
new = [transform(o) for o in old]
```

Your question then is "can I write a function to transform", which is "yes" if there is any way to describe what you are trying to do (your example is far from complete):

```
def transform(old):
    return {new(k): v for k, v in old.items() if condition(k, v)}

def new(key):
    return {'old_key_1': 'new_key1', ...}[key]

def condition(key, value):
    if key == 'old_key_2' and value == 'value2b':
         return False
    return True
```

Comment: Excellent suggestion. Hadn't thought about a pattern like that but makes perfect sense.

Comment: One follow up here. If I want to also transform specific values in different ways, say some .upper some .lower, I'm not sure how that fits into this. Seems you'd need a new transform_value() function and have to call it twice, once in condition() and then again in {new(k): new(v) ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trick and, as a rule a thumb, *you should avoid tricks if possible*.

```
new_dict_list = [
    {
        'new_key1': old_dict['old_key_1'],
        'new_key3': old_dict['old_key_3'],
        **({} if old_dict['old_key_2'].endswith("b") else {'new_key2': old_dict['old_key_2']})
    }
    for old_dict in old_dict_list
]

print(new_dict_list)
# [{'new_key1': 'value1a', 'new_key3': 'value3a', 'new_key2': 'value2a'}, {'new_key1': 'value1b', 'new_key3': 'value3b'}]
```

I used the `**` operator to unpack a dict. This dict is either `{}` if the condtion is met, or `{'new_key2': old_dict['old_key_2']}` if the condition is not met. Hence, the key `new_key2` is only created if the condtion is not met.

In this example, the condition is `old_dict['old_key_2'].endswith("b")`, but you can set any other condition on the `old_dict`.